# Excel VBA: Count # of Delimiters

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub CopyTest()

    Dim skuRow As Integer
    Dim curSku As String
    Dim numSkus As Integer
    Dim impType As String
    Dim copyRows As Integer
    Dim supAcc As String
    Dim arr_TotalList As Variant
    Dim locs As String
    Dim colorMax As String

    With ActiveSheet
        copyRows = 3
        impType = "-LE"
        supAcc = ""
        numSkus = Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        skuRow = 1

        Rows("1:" & copyRows).Copy

        For i = copyRows + 1 To (copyRows * numSkus) + 1 Step copyRows
            arr_TotalList = Split(CurVal, "|")
            colorMax = Sheets(2).Range("C" & skuRow).Value
            If colorMax = "" Then
                colorMax = "4"
            End If

            curSku = Sheets(2).Range("A" & skuRow).Value
            locs = Sheets(2).Range("B" & skuRow).Value
            arr_TotalList = Split(locs, "|")
            Range("A" & i).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            For n = 0 To copyRows - 1 Step 1
                If n = 0 Then
                    Range("B" & i + n) = supAcc & curSku & impType
                    Range("E" & i + n) = colorMax
                Else
                    Range("G" & i + n) = arr_TotalList(n - 1)
                    Range("B" & i + n) = supAcc & curSku & impType
                End If
            Next n

            skuRow = skuRow + 1

        Next i            
    End With

End Sub
```

This code basically uses a data template in Sheet 1 and copies that template and implements data from Sheet 2 how ever many times set in "copyRows"

Right now, I would have to adjust the template in Sheet 1 each time I change "copyRows" number. For example if copyRows is 4, in Sheet 1, the template would contain 4 rows of predefined stuff, the first row is required, the following rows is based on the "|" delimiter of values in Sheet 2's data. For example, Sheet 2 column B has data like, "Test1|Test2|Test3"

I am trying to automate this code a little further so I do not have to manually change copyRows and add or remove additional rows in the template sheet. In the template sheet, I want to just have two rows, the first is required, the second will be based on the number of "|" delimiter values.

I am thinking of adding a count formula for the copyRows, for example, `=LEN(Sheets(2).B:B)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheets(2).B:B,"|",""))` and then adding 1. How would I put in the formula in for copyRows?

Comment: `ubound(arr_TotalList)` should be the upper bound of the index of arr_totalList after you perform the Split on "|". If I remember correctly, Ubound would normally report the index *count* which is normally 1 greater than the index (so `x(Ubound(x)-1)` would be the highest index), but on a Variant it returns the highest index instead (so `x(ubound(x)` is highest). [Check this]

Comment: Agree with @Yorik, if I understand everything. In the case where you don't yet have `arr_TotalList` defined yet when you're setting `copyRows` up, you could set `copyRows = 1 + UBound(Split(Sheets(2).Range("B" & skuRow).Value))` though.

Answer (score 0):

This function will find the number of occurrences of a "|" character in column B of your worksheet.

```
Function FindDelimeters()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim DelimCount As Long
lastrow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

DelimCount = Sheets(2).Evaluate("=SUM(LEN(B1:B" & lastrow & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1:B" & lastrow & ",""|"","""")))")
FindDelimeters = DelimCount

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the source data looks like, but I think you could define skuRow first, and then set up copyRows as follows:

```
copyRows = 1 + UBound(Split(Sheets(2).Range("B" & skuRow).Value, "|"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Other options

`=COUNTIF(B:B/"*|*")`

`Application.CountIf(Sheets(2).Columns(2), "*|*")`